# Web component interaction with button click event

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have a custom HTML element `x-icicle` over which I have full control, I would like to have it interact with an HTML button (that could be anywhere in the DOM), e.g., every time the button is pressed I would like some JS to be executed in `x-icicle`.

```html
<button></button>
<x-icicle></x-icicle>
```

```js
class Icicle extends HTMLElement {
  // ...
  if (buttom_pressed) {
    // something
  }
}
customElements.define('x-icicle', Icicle);
```

I do not know how to send the button event to `x-icicle`. Perhaps setting a callback somehow?

Any hints?

Comment: `btn.addEventListener("click", () => { elem.style.color = "red"; })`?

Comment: Thanks @D.Pardal for the reply. The color change was more of an example, the actual situation is more complicated than that. I tried to clarify this in the question.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by some JS code being executed in an element. The comment from @Nico Schlömer is as good as any way to execute code which does things with your element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Take a look at the example below (I used a simple `span` instead of your custom element but it would be exactly the same)

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const span = document.getElementById('span');

button.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    span.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myEvent'));
});

span.addEventListener('myEvent', evt => {
    span.innerHTML = 'button has been clicked';
});
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button>
<span id="span"></span>
```

Comment: Don't forget the ``composed:true`` Custom Event setting when the dispatch is done within a shadowDOM, to make it bubble up/outside shadowDOM

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method to your custom element class

```js
class Icicle extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-icicle element initiated')
  }

  listen(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Button clicked')
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('x-icicle', Icicle)

document.querySelector('x-icicle').listen(document.querySelector('button'))
```

```html
<button>
  Button
</button>

<x-icicle></x-icicle>
```